# SQL query to add message to PostgreSQL server log file

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, libpqxx

For the [HelpCovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid) GPLv3+ web server application (git [commit `dff3ab1521ed579cbf2`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/dff3ab1521ed579cbf2276694057cfac3007a3e8) at end of March 2020, probably in function `hcv_initialize_database`  of [our file `hcv_database.cc`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_database.cc#L145)) in C++ for Linux (work in progress) using libpqxx with PostgreSQL 11 on Debian/Buster, we would like at startup time to issue one single SQL query which adds a message to the PostGreSQL log file (e.g. `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log` in our test environment).

The intuition would be that just after creating the tables we would issue some SQL like

> `--- wrong fictional PostgreSQL query`
>
> `ADD TO POSTGRESQL LOG FILE ("start of helpcovid pid 1234 commit dff3ab1521ed+ on localhost");`

with the hope that something similar to

```
2020-03-31 17:00:01.656 CEST [13262] helpcovid_usr@helpcovid_db start of helpcovid pid 1234 commit dff3ab1521ed+ on localhost
```

would be added to `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log`   ...

This mostly to facilitate debugging and paging that  `postgresql-11-main.log` file (or syslogs, if PostgreSQL logs there).

Is there a quick and dirty way to achieve this?

Perhaps [`RAISE NOTICE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), but how  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `DO` statement:

```
DO $$BEGIN RAISE LOG 'whatever'; END;$$;
```

Messages of level `LOG` get written to the log file.

Comment: Thanks a big lot. Will try that soon. Why the `$$`  ?

Comment: It is another form of string quoting. You can use `'`, but then you have to double the apostrophes in the code.

Comment: The `libpqxx`  will quote arguments appropriately. As a cybersecurity professional, I am aware of SQL injections

Comment: In this case, SQL injection is not the issue, because the code is a string constant written by the programmer. But it is annoying to write `DO 'BEGIN RAISE LOG ''whatever''; END;';`.